# Batch script: Selecting filename which has multiple dots

Tags: batch-file

I have a compiler output which is a hex file and am going to compare the first line for a  certain text and adds it if it not there. But the hex file output format is `something.another.again.hex`. How to select this hex file from a folder. I am running the batch file from the same folder.

Here is my code, can some one correct it?

```
@echo on
for %%i In (*.*.*.hex) Do (
      echo %%i
      set /p var= <%%i 
      if NOT %var% == sometext (
        echo sometext >temp.hex
        type %%i >> temp.hex
        del %%i
        ren temp.hex %%i
    )
)
```

The file is not selected and it prints nothing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need delayed expansion to use a variable inside a block (between `(` and `)`:

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i In (*.*.*.hex) Do (
      echo %%i
      set /p var= <%%i 
      if NOT !var! == sometext (
        echo sometext >temp.hex
        type %%i >> temp.hex
        del %%i
        ren temp.hex %%i
    )
)
```

Comment: The comparison doesn't work when using this method. It adds the sometext even it is present.

Comment: works fine here. Check `var`. It will fail, if there is an additional space in it. (use `echo var: -!var!-` after the `set /p`)

Comment: Works perfectly. Removed space after !var!